# Should I enable "Anonymously with Google and others" in Analytics to see my site in Website trends

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics

I want my site to be appear in [Website Trends](http://trends.google.com/websites?q=wikipedia.org). I have Google Analytics on my site, and my site is listed on Website Trends, but there is no data.
I have enabled (long time ago) the "With other Google products only" option.

Do I have to enable "Anonymously with Google and others" option to be my site in Website Trends?

Answer (score 1):

Basically yes - not wholly unreasonably if you want to use other people's data Google requires you to share yours. So. Yes.

Comment: I thought that Googlw Webtrends IS a Google product. And I have checked the "With other Google products only", so with Webtrends I share the data.

Comment: @netmano you're looking at google zeitgist there, you need to log in to google analytics, enable data sharing and then you'll be able to view benchmarking data. Google 'Google analytics benchmarking'